# Open BASH Shell Script files without terminal

Tags: scripts, filemanager

How  do you run shell script files without using the terminal in Ubuntu? Like just double clicking it. I know in Xubuntu it does it like that but not regular Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Edit > Preferences > Behavior and check the option "Run executable text files when they are opened"

[image]

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know that.